# Finding the inverse of double branched function $f$

Tags: functions

Yesterday I've stumbled upon a problem which seems trivial at first but I can't seem to get it right.

Given $f : \mathbb R  \to \mathbb R, f(x) = \begin{cases} x + m, x \ge 1 \\ -x^2 + 2x, x \lt 1 \end{cases} $
a) For $ m = 0 $, prove $f$ invertible and determine $f^{-1}$.
I solved this and found out $f^{-1}(x) = \begin{cases} x , x \ge 1 \\ -1 \pm \sqrt{x+1}, x \lt 1 \end{cases} $ .
b) Solve $ 4[f(x) - f^{-1}(x)] = 7+7x$.
This is where I'm stuck because it's unclear for me which branch should I choose for $f(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x)$. Should I solve it twice for $x\ge1$ and $x\lt1$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's the correct approach. Although be on the look out for solutions that are inconsistent with the case you're considering. If you solve the equation for $x \geq 1$ and you get, say, $x=0$, then you know that solution is incorrect because it violates your initial condition that $x \geq 1$.